# Checking for equality of RDDs

Tags: java, junit, equals, apache-spark

I making some tests in JUnit and I need to check the equality of two Spark RDDs.

A way I thought of doing it is this:

```
JavaRDD<SomeClass> expResult = ...;
JavaRDD<SomeClass> result = ...;

assertEquals(expResult.collect(), result.collect());
```

Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the expected result is reasonably small, it's best to `collect` RDD data and compare it locally (just like you've written).

When it's necessary to use large enough datasets in tests, there are few other possibilities:

**Disclaimer**: I'm not familiar enough with Spark Java API, so I'll write further sample code in Scala. I hope it won't be a problem, since it might be either rewritten in Java or converted into a couple of utility functions invoked from Java code.

#### Method 1: Zip RDDs together and compare item-by-item

This method is only usable if the order of elements in RDD is well defined (i.e., RDDs are sorted).

```
val diff = expResult
  .zip(result)
  .collect { case (a, b) if a != b => a -> b }
  .take(100)
```

The `diff` array will contain up to 100 differentiating pairs. If the RDDs are big enough, and you'd like to obtain all items from `diff` locally, it's possible to use `toLocalIterator` method. It's better not to use `collect` method, since you may run OOM.

This method is probably the fastest, since it doesn't require shuffle, but it might be only used if the order of partitions in RDDs and the order of items in partitions is well defined.

#### Method 2: Co-group RDDs

This method might be used to test if the `result` RDD contains specified (possibly non-unique) values without any particular order

```
  val diff = expResult.map(_ -> 1)
    .cogroup(result.map(_ -> 1))
    .collect { case (a, (i1, i2)) if i1.sum != i2.sum => a -> (i1.sum - i2.sum) }
    .take(100)
```

The `diff` array will contain the differentiating values together with difference between amounts.

For example:

- if `expResult` contains single instance of some value and `result` doesn't contain that value, the number will be `+1`;
- If `result` contains 3 instances of another value, and `expResult` only 1, the number will be `-2`.

This method will be faster than other options (i.e., substracting RDDs from each other), since it requires only one shuffle.

Comment: I guess for now I will continue using the `collect()` method since my data is quite small (albeit in the form of `result.collect().removeAll(expResult.collect())` and then assert that `result` is empty since I've found this to be a better way to check equality of two lists). It is very good to know my options for the future though in case I return bigger collections.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Spark into Java, just use the collect method didn't worked. The result of assertEquals was always false.

So this test:

```
assertEquals( 
  this.fooExpectedRddTest.collect(),
  this.fooServiceTest.getRdd().collect()
);
```

Generate this result:

```
FooServiceTest.getRdd:143 expected: 

scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper<[
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":1496405614}, 
    {"a":1,"b":3,"c":1496243614}, 
    {"a":2,"b":2,"c":1496416414}
]> 

but was: 

scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper<[
    {"a":1,"b":2,"c":1496405614}, 
    {"a":1,"b":3,"c":1496243614}, 
    {"a":2,"b":2,"c":1496416414}
]>
```

My way to deal with that was converting them into something more easy to compare

```
List<Tuple3<Integer,Integer,Double>> expectedList = this.fooExpectedRddTest.map(
        (Foo foo) -> {
            return new Tuple3<Integer,Integer,Double>(
                    foo.getA(),
                    foo.getB(),
                    foo.getC()
            );
        }
).collect();

List<Tuple3<Integer,Integer,Double>> receivedList = this.fooServiceTest.getRdd().map(
        (Foo foo) -> {
            return new Tuple3<Integer,Integer,Double>(
                    foo.getA(),
                    foo.getB(),
                    foo.getC()
            );
        }
).collect();

assertEquals(
    expectedList,
    receivedList
);
```